# How should i execute a SQL query in spring boot in the browser

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm new to spring boot i'm developing a spring boot application to manage the employees, and i'm in the database stage, in my control I've added a SQL query that allows to select the employees compared to a base field (techno and date), how can I run these queries on a browser

My interfaceDao is:

```
public interface employesDao extends JpaRepository <employes, Integer>{

    public List<employes>findByNomContains(Date date);
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public List<employes>findByNomContains(List<List> techno);
```

the controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class employesController {

    @Autowired
    employesDao employestdao;

    // Affiche la liste de tous les employes dans la base
    @GetMapping(value = "/employes")
    public List<employes> listeDesemployes(){

        List<employes> employes = employesdao.findAll();

        if(employes.isEmpty()) throw new ProductNotFoundException("Aucun employes n'est enregistréer dans la base");

        return employes;

     }

    //Ajouter un employes
    @PostMapping(value = "/Addemployes")
    public employes ajouterProduit(@RequestBody employes employes) {

        employes employesAdded = employesdao.save(employes);

       return employesAdded;
    }

}
```

Comment: Probably with http://localhost:8080/api/employes, otherwise I would suggest you use api development tools like curl or postman to test your apis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably try `POST http://localhost:8080/api/Addemployes` using a REST client  (Postman or YARC for example) instead of a browser if you want to access this endpoint right away. Otherwise you need to develop a form to interact with it (creating the `employe` first then calling the `POST /api/Addemployes` endpoint).

As a general comment, I would not call the endpoint `Addemployes` but just the same as the `GET` endpoint. REST rules alone let the user understand that a `POST` will create a new entity. Also, use a code linter like SonarLint for example, your syntax is not standard and such tools let you know in real time what is wrong.